# DataPropertyName used on another column

Tags: c#, autogeneratecolumn

I'm tired of searching and I can't figure out. Probably this isn't possible.

```
string query = "SELECT cust.id, cust.name, cust.photo, country.description
                FROM customers AS cust
                INNER JOIN countries AS country ON country.id = cust.id_country"

/* etc.. command ..*/
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "customers");
```

Ok, after doing this I disable the `AutoGenerateColumns`, I do set the `DataSource` and finally I create the columns by hand.

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["customers"];

var _name = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { 
    HeaderText = "Name",
    DataPropertyName = "name"
};
var _photo = new DataGridViewImageColumn() { 
    HeaderText = "",
    Image = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "/customers/" + ????????)
};
```

So, my problem is on the "???" characters. How do I set in that place the `cust.photo` field? 
The `cust.photo` retrieves the name of the photo, something like `"ske_213f.jpg"`

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? Why `"ske_213f.jpg"` is not working for you?

Comment: Well, I have 10 rows in database, each user has a photo..the "ske_213f.jpg" was an example.